# Fuel pump fuse location

Tags: diesel, dodge, fuse, ram

Where is the fuse for the fuel Pump located in the fuse relay box for a 2004 Dodge Ram 2500?  I am trying to find out if I need to change my fuel pump or just the fuse.  I am not getting any readings on my electric wiring to my fuel pump.

Comment: Should be fuse 17 in the TIPM It's unclear on whether the relay is soldered to the TIPM or not though.

Comment: Number 17 turned out to be a spare.

Comment: Which engine do you have?